# SwiftUI in iOS14 Keyboard Avoidance for bottom View

Tags: ios, swiftui, keyboard, keyboard-avoidance

In iOS14 `SwiftUI` introduced automatic keyboard avoidance. I have form in scrollView that take all screen expect bottom where I have a fixed button.

I want to ignore keyboard avoidance for that button but keep it for scrollView so the textfields move when the keyboard appears.

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
               TextField("Testing", text: $text)
            }
            Button("Validate", action: action)
              //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) second try
        }
        //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) first try
    }
}
```

First try: this applies globally, the bottom of the scrollView won't be accessible when keyboard is open.

Second try: this doesn't do anything (Button stays above the keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

I actually just ran into this issue myself. I think there is a bug in SwiftUI that is causing the button to keep the keyboard avoidance.

I found a workaround that could be helpful depending on requirements. I hide the bottom button whenever a user is entering text. Since you can't see the button anyway where the keyboard is up. It is not super elegant. But hopefully in future versions of SwiftUI the `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` will work for this use case.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = ""
    @FocusState var isFieldFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                TextField("Testing", text: $text)
                    .focused($isFieldFocused)
            }
            if !isFieldFocused {
                Button("Some title", action: {})
            }
        }
    }
}
```